# jsonify не работает

Tags: python-3.x, json

Подскажите, кипит мзг, пытаюсь разобраться с jsonify

В инете примеры:

```
from flask import jsonify, Flask
import json
appFlask = Flask(__name__)
@appFlask.route('/home_jsonify')
def home_jsonify():
Dictionary ={'username':'eduCBA' , 'account':'Premium' , 'validity':'2709 days'}
return jsonify(Dictionary)
```

У них получается так:
[картинка](https://cdn.educba.com/academy/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Flask-jsonify-3.jpg.webp)

У меня в дну строчку, что не делай!!!

```
{"account":"Premium","username":"eduCBA","validity":"2709 days"}
```

Comment: У них так выводиться потому, что расширение установлено в браузера. Установите  `JSON Formatter`, или `JSONVue`, и у вас будет так же.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отказаться от `jsonify` в пользу [`flask.json.dumps`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.json.dumps):

```py
return json.dumps(Dictionary, indent=4)
```

---

Если же вы хотите сделать "красивую печать" для всех представлений, то попробуйте установить глобальную настройку [`JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/config/#JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR):

```py
appFlask.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] = True
```

Кстати, данная настройка всегда включена в режиме отладки. Наверное, поэтому

> У них получается так [красиво]